# Remote triggers on Adobe XD Prototype

Tags: adobe-xd

I need to create a prototype of a phone receiving an incoming call using Adobe XD, that is controlled remotely. Ideally, I would hook up a Bluetooth device (a keyboard for example) and trigger the movent from an artboard that's back (to simulate the phone being off) to an incoming call screen. Does anyone know a way of achieving this in Adobe XD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out not to be possible, so I used photopie.io which works a treat.